# Find the difference between two cells of text in Excel

Tags: excel, formulas, excel-2016

I have 2 cells that have lists of numbers in them separated by commas (,). The list in `K` is the full set, the list in `D` is the partial set. I would like to put into `M` the part of `K` that is not in `D`.

example:

`K4 = 1,2,5,6`

`D4 = 1,5,6`

Result `M4 = 2`

I have used `SUBSTITUTE`, but that only works when the numbers in `D` are in order and not missing anything from the middle of `K`.

I need a non-VBA answer, please.

Comment: The best answer might be don't store your data in CSV format.  Excel, like databases, probably doesn't handle CSV data too well.  If you had this data spread out across multiple rows, it would be easier to handle your question.

Comment: Two questions. (1) Are the number of elements in column K always 4? Can there be none? Can there be blank spaces following a comma? (2) Would you be open to a solution which uses a helper column, or even several of them, to arrive at the solution?

Comment: @Variatus there can be more or less than 4 values, that was just the simplest to show an example.

Comment: @ScottCraner I do not have an O365 subscription.

Comment: Then my answer should work without the need of the udf.

Comment: Depending on how often you need to do this -- ie whether it is a one-off manipulation or needs to be an easily refreshable system -- you could convert your comma-separated lists to values in multiple columns using Data > Text to Columns. Then it would be easier to write formulae that compare differences across the resulting columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a formula that will work for a single missing value. If you need to return more than one missing value, helper columns could be used, but VBA would be much simpler. The formula is normally entered and should work with most versions of Excel:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/ISERR(SEARCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(K4,",",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),D4 & ",")),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(K4,",",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)))
```

`seq_99` is a defined Name (formula, in this case) that generates an array of values `{1,99,198,297, ...}`

```
seq_99  Refers to:  =IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))-1)*99)
```

For a VBA routine, recommended especially if there might be more than one missing item, try the following:

```
Option Explicit
Function MissingValues(sFull As String, sPartial As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object
    Dim sPat As String
    Dim S As String

'Replace commas with pipes, surround by brackets "[]" and follow by end
'  of line to create regex pattern from sPartial
sPat = "[" & Replace(sPartial, ",", "|") & "](?:,|$)"

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = sPat
    .ignorecase = True
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    S = .Replace(sFull, "")
    .Pattern = ",$"
    MissingValues = .Replace(S, "")
End With

End Function
```

The routine uses Regular Expression to delete everything in the full set that appears in the partial set.  (And then a final check to remove any terminal comma).  This will return multiple missing values in the same comma-separated pattern.  It is case insensitive, but you can see where that can be easily changed.

Here is a screen shot comparing the output of the two methods when there are two missing values:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have a subscription to Office 365 Excel then you can use this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("," &TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(K4,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(K4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(K4,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999))&",",","&D4&",")),"",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(K4,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(K4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(K4,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999))))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when Exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

---

I understand you asked for a non vba answer, but;

If you do not have a subscription to Office 365 Excel You can put this code in a module attached to the workbook and use the formula as described above.

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

Comment: I find the second solution very interesting, but I do not get it to work. If I understand correctly, then you pass a range like A1:B6 somehow to the function. And in the middle part it looks if the array has more than one dimension. And then it somehow calls the function recursively and does something. But my two questions are, how do I pass the range to the function (UDF?) and what is this rest where it extracts the differences, like a diff on the shell?